# Creating gantt chart in C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, charts, devexpress, gantt-chart

I need a help creating gantt chart, that will look like this below
[image]
I am using DevExpress 12.2, and WinForms.

It doesn't need to be done with DevEpress, I just need to get that look.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since this was asked, but I've wanted something like this too. I looked at other WinForms Gantt Chart controls available and found they were pretty complicated. So I made a simple, yet highly-customizable Gantt Chart for WinForms: https://github.com/derekantrican/GanttChart . No DevExpress required

However, the "month view" that you want isn't implemented yet

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this work for wpf

Comment: @AP the project is not directly built for WPF, but this article might be able to help you out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-composite-control-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I last used DevExpress, but I recently used the following open source control, which is quite easy to implement and well-documented. I strongly suggest you to take a look into it.

[Codeplex - .NET Winforms Gantt Chart Control](https://ganttchart.codeplex.com/)

Also, you could probably do something with the Chart control of .NET but that will just require a lot more work, so I'd give the link I put above a shot.

Comment: Since codeplex is shutting down, I have moved the project to github https://github.com/jakesee/ganttchart/ and looking to add more features and add timeline support for hours and minutes as well in v2.0

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are looking for a full-featured interactive Gantt view, you can also check the [Scheduler Control - Gantt View](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/10698/controls-and-libraries/scheduler/views/gantt-view).